# How do I return a list from a custom object in Salesforce using javascript on a button?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have a custom object in Salesforce called Website_Role__c.  This object has a list of people associated with a store with different roles (Owner, Mentor, etc.).

Using JavaScript in a Salesforce button on Account:

The desired behavior is a user clicks the button and a dialog pops up with the list of people in the Website_Role__c for that Account.  There would be a checkbox next to each person allowing the user to select them.

We are using eSign (formerly EchoSign).  This button is a "Send with eSign" button that will be used to send an agreement to the list of people from Website_Role__c.

This is where I am at now:

```js
/*My Attempt*/
{
    !REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")
} //adds the proper code for inclusion of AJAX toolkit
var url = parent.location.href; //string for the URL of the current page
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Website_Role__c)
}; //grabs the Website Role records for the currently selected store
var updateRecords = []; //array for holding records that this code will ultimately update

if (records[0] == null) { //if the button was clicked but there was no record selected
    alert("Please select at least one person to send to."); //alert the user that they didn't make a selection 
} else { //otherwise, there was a person selected
    for (var a = 0; a < records.length; a++) { //for all records
        var update_Website_Role__c = new sforce.SObject("Website_Role__c"); //create a new sObject for storing updated record details
//This is where I get lost. Not sure if this is even the correct approach
    }
//??
    parent.location.href = url; //refresh the page
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Owner__c, Mentor__c FROM Website_Role__c WHERE Account__c ='{!Account.Id}'");
var records = query.getArray("records");

alert("Owner is: " + records[0].Owner__c);
```

This assumes you have a reference field on your Website_Role object that points to the Account.
Check here for some more examples
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm